# Finding a location on cosine curve with a specified distance to another location JS

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I am working on a "rally" game where a car is drawing on hills made of cosine curves. I know the current `xspeed` of the car (without hills) but the problem is that I need to know the `xspeed` of the car on the hills to be able to draw the wheels on right places and keep the speed steady.

At the moment my solution looks like this.

```
function drawWheelOnBasicHill(hillStart, xLocWheel, wheelNro) {
var cw = 400 //the width of the hill
t_max = 2*Math.PI; 
var scale = 80, step = cw, inc = t_max/step; 

    var t1 = (xLocWheel-hillStart)*inc 
    var y1 = -scale*0.5 * Math.cos(t1);

    if(wheelNro == 1 ){ //backwheel
         drawRotatedImage(wheel, car.wheel1x, car.wheel1y-y1-45,sx); 
//drawing the wheel on canvas
    } else { //frontwheel
        drawRotatedImage(wheel, car.wheel2x, car.wheel2y-y1-45,sx);
    }


   for(var i=1; i<=car.speed; i++){ //finding the next xlocation of the wheel with the
   //same distance (on the curve) to the previous location as the speed of the car(=the
   //distance to the new point on the flat ground)
        var t2 = (xLocWheel + i -hillStart)*inc
        var y2 = -scale*0.5 * Math.cos(t2);

        if(Math.round(Math.sqrt(i^2+(y2-y1)^2))==car.speed){
            sx = sx+i; //the new xcoordinate break; 
        }
    }

}
```

The `for` loop is the problem. It might bee too slow (animation with fps 24). I cant understand why the `if` statement isnt working at the moment. It works sometimes but most of the times the value of the condition newer reaches the actual `xspeed`.

Are there some more efficient and easier ways to do this? Or does this code contain some errors? I really appreciate your efforts to solve this! Ive been looking at this piece of code the whole day..

Answer (score 0):

So i is the variable and

```
x2=x1+i
t2=t1+i*inc
y1=-scale*0.5 * Math.cos(t1)
y2=-scale*0.5 * Math.cos(t2)
```

which somehow is strange. The landscape should be time independent, that is, y should be a function of x only. The time step is external, determined by the speed of the animation loop. So a more logical model would have dx as variable and

```
dt = t2-t1
x2 = x1 + dx
y1 = f(x1) = -0.5*scale*cos(x1)
y2 = f(x2) = -0.5*scale*cos(x2)
```

and you would be looking for the intersection of

```
(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2 = (speed*dt)^2
```

which simplifies to

```
(speed*dt)^2=dx^2+0.25*scale^2*(cos(x1+dx)-cos(x1))^2
```

For small values of dx, which would be the case if dt or speed*dt is small,

```
cos(x1+dx)-cos(x1) is approx. -sin(x1)*dx
```

leading to

```
dx = (speed*dt) / sqrt( 1+0.25*scale^2*sin(x1)^2 )
```

To get closer to the intersection of curve and circle, you can then iterate the fixed point equation

```
dydx = 0.5*scale*(cos(x1+dx)-cos(x1))/dx
dx = (speed*dt) / ( 1+dydx^2 )
```

a small number of times.